# selecting rows in dataTable to show data from another table in Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, shiny

So I have this dataframe...

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
   Project     Counts     Inventory
      A          25         100
      B          20         120
      C          10          50
 ",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and this dataframe....

```
df2 <- read.table(text="
   Project     Sub_Project     Counts       Date
      A            1              5      2017-05-01
      A            2             10      2017-05-01
      A            2             10      2017-06-01
      B            1             40      2017-05-01
      B            1             20      2017-06-01
      B            1             20      2017-07-01
      B            2             40      2017-05-01
      C            1             15      2017-05-01
      C            1             35      2017-06-01
 ",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In shiny using `library(DT)` and `library(ggplot2)` I'm making a `renderDataTable` of `df1` that allows you to select each row, and as each row is selected it begins displaying another datatable. What I want to do is, when I click on a row in `df1`, the new datatable that gets rendered will give me a subset of `df2`, displaying only the information of the Project selected, summarising the counts, and still organizing them by Sub_Project, like this (if you were to click on Project A of `df1`:

```
df3 <-read.table(text="
   Project     Sub_Project     Counts
      A            1              5
      A            2             20
 ",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The actual functionality of what I'm trying to do works, I just don't know how to logically program what I want... Here is my whole app

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)

df1 <- read.table(text="
            Project     Counts     Inventory
              A          25         100
              B          20         120
              C          10          50
              ",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df2 <- read.table(text="
           Project     Sub_Project     Counts       Date
              A            1              5      2017-05-01
              A            2             10      2017-05-01
              A            2             10      2017-06-01
              B            1             40      2017-05-01
              B            1             20      2017-06-01
              B            1             20      2017-07-01
              B            2             40      2017-05-01
              C            1             15      2017-05-01
              C            1             35      2017-06-01
              ",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'Dashboard'),
  dashboardSidebar(),

  dashboardBody(

tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel('Sequencing', 
           fluidRow(
             column(12, 
                  dataTableOutput('project_table'), 
                  dataTableOutput('subproject_table'))
           )
         )
)
)
 )



server <- function(input, output) { 

  output$project_table <- renderDataTable(df1, options = list(pageLength = 10))


  output$subproject_table <- renderDataTable({
     s = input$project_table_rows_selected
      if(length(s)) df1[s, , drop=FALSE]})
 }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: IN the `df3`, the `counts` 20 seems to be coming from the row where 'Project' is 'B' on 'df2'

Comment: @akrun no what it's doing is summarizing the Counts from the same Sub_Project in Project A. So it's ignoring date information, and keeping `df1` organized by Project and and then summing the counts by similar Sub_Projects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what are You looking for:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)

df1 <- read.table(text="
                  Project     Counts     Inventory
                  A          25         100
                  B          20         120
                  C          10          50
                  ",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df2 <- read.table(text="
                  Project     Sub_Project     Counts       Date
                  A            1              5      2017-05-01
                  A            2             10      2017-05-01
                  A            2             10      2017-06-01
                  B            1             40      2017-05-01
                  B            1             20      2017-06-01
                  B            1             20      2017-07-01
                  B            2             40      2017-05-01
                  C            1             15      2017-05-01
                  C            1             35      2017-06-01
                  ",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'Dashboard'),
  dashboardSidebar(),

  dashboardBody(

    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel('Sequencing', 
               fluidRow(
                 column(12, 
                        dataTableOutput('project_table'), 
                        dataTableOutput('subproject_table'))
               )
      )
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) { 

  output$project_table <- renderDataTable(df1, options = list(pageLength = 10))


  output$subproject_table <- renderDataTable({
    s = input$project_table_rows_selected
    project <- unique(df1[s,c("Project")])
    df2[df2$Project %in% project, ]})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have created new object `project` which will be a vector of unique variables in column `Project` from `df1`. Then on base of it i filtered `df2`.